# AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, html, css, flask, backend

In rendering an html template, the minutes_id is not being passed through correctly. It's throwing the error: "AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'get'". I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is the line of code tripping me up.
`minutes = club.minutes.get(minutes_id) #GET THE Minutes for specific DAY`

**routes.py:**

```
@clubs.route("/view_minutes/<int:user_id>/<int:club_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def view_minutes(user_id, club_id):
    club = Club.query.get_or_404(club_id)
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    minutes = club.minutes
    #if click "export" -->
        #return render_pdf(url_for('minutes_pdf', user_id=user_id, club_id=club_id))
    return render_template('view_minutes.html', title='View', user=user, club=club, minutes=minutes)

@clubs.route("/minutes_pdf/<int:user_id>/<int:club_id>/<int:minutes_id>.pdf", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def minutes_pdf(user_id, club_id, minutes_id):
    club = Club.query.get_or_404(club_id)
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    minutes = club.minutes.get(minutes_id) #GET THE Minutes for specific DAY
    return render_template('view_minutes_pdf.html', club=club, minutes=minutes)
```

**models.py**

```
user_club_assoc_table = db.Table('user_club_assoc_table',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('club_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('club.id')))

roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles',
                backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=ROLES['student'])
    clubs = db.relationship('Club', secondary=user_club_assoc_table)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}' #return f'User(firstname={self.firstname!r}, lastname={self.lastname!r})'


class Club(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    members = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_club_assoc_table)
    minutes = db.relationship('Minutes', backref='club')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'#Club(name={self.name!r})

class Minutes(db.Model): 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    club_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('club.id'))
    date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False) #0000-00-00
    time = db.Column(db.Time) #00:00:00
    location = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    attendance = db.relationship('Attendance', backref='minutes', lazy=True) #check code
    purchase =  db.Column(db.Text)
    purchasemotion = db.Column(db.Text)
    fundraiser = db.Column(db.Text)
    fundmotion = db.Column(db.Text)
    minute = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False) #notes
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.club_id} {self.date}'

class Attendance(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    present = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False) #set correctly
    minutes_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('minutes.id'))
```

Comment: The error says everything. Look at the definition of class Minutes. There is no attribute called `minutes_id`, if you are looking for the `id` of minutes then your code has to be `club.minutes.id`

Comment: How would I fix this error so that I can access the data from one specific id for club.minutes (like I did for Club and User)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the url you are already capturing `minute_id` why don't you query directly

```
Minutes.query.get_or_404(minute_id)
```